# R Shiny selectize observeEvent on all choices made

Tags: r, triggers, shiny, observable

I have the following `Shiny` app and I would like for the observeEvent to only trigger when all choices are made from the selectizeInput UI. The reason for this is that I have a dynamic number of maxItems (which i set arbitrarily to 2 for this example) so I cannot just base the observeEvent off the `length`. Importantly I also have a script running on the observeEvent, which I only want to run only one time - once the selectizeInput is "deselected". The alternative is to go with an actionbutton but I would like if possible to retain the automation / smoothness of the app.

Reproducible example below

```
library(shiny)


ui <- fluidPage(

   uiOutput("server_lala")

   ,
   textOutput("choices")

)


server <- function(input, output)
{

   output$server_lala <- renderUI({


      temperature <- c(7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6)

      selectizeInput( inputId = "lala",
                      choices = paste(temperature),
                      label= "2. Select type",
                      multiple = TRUE,
                      size = 10,
                      width = '100%',
                      options = list( placeholder = 'Type',
                                      maxItems = 2
                      )
      )
   })

   observeEvent(input$lala  , {

      output$choices <- renderText({
         paste("Selectize has a length of", input$lala)
      })

   })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Maybe make `maxItems` a `reactiveVal`, in that case you could base it on the length?

Comment: The users should be able to pick 1 through 10 inputs in the selectize, so any length based triggers will fail.

Comment: How is that number between 1 and 10 decided?

Comment: By the users. If they want to see 5 time series, they will pick 5. If they want to only see 1 they will pick one. Right now the `observeEvent` triggers once the first selection is made and then again once the second selection is made, etc..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try something like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  numericInput('howmany','How many inputs?',min=1,max=10,value=2,step=1),
  selectizeInput('myselect','select options',multiple=TRUE, choices= seq(1,10), options = list(placeholder='type')),
  textOutput('mytext')

)


server <- function(input, output,session)
{

  all_selected <- reactiveVal('Not all inputs selected.')

  observeEvent(input$howmany, {
    updateSelectizeInput(session, 'myselect', options = list(maxItems = input$howmany))
  })

  observeEvent(input$myselect,{
    if(length(input$myselect)==input$howmany)
    {
      all_selected('All inputs selected!')
    }
  })

  output$mytext <- renderText({all_selected()})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```